# hook_cron() doesn't get any value from taxonomy_get_tree()

Tags: taxonomy-terms, cron, users

I am using the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
  function mymodule_cron() {
    // ...

    _update_user_categories($uid);

    // ...
  }

    function _update_user_categories($uid) {

      $articleCategories = array();
      $user = user_load($uid, TRUE);

    // Fill array with user access categories
      foreach ($user->field_article_category['und'] as $index => $tid) {
        $articleCategories[] = $tid['tid'];
      }

    // Generate SQL statement for Multi record insert
      $values = array();
      $accessValues = array();
      foreach ($articleCategories as $index => $value) {
        $accessValues[] = $value;
        $terms = taxonomy_get_tree(2, $value);
    // Loop for all children to add them in the $accessValues;
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
          $accessValues [] = $term->tid;
        }
      }
      $categories = array();        
      foreach (array_unique($accessValues) as $index => $value) {
        if ($value) {
          $values[$value] = "($uid,$value,'taxonomy')";
          if (!in_array($value, $categories)) {
            $categories [] = array('tid' => $value);
          }
        }
      }

      $insValues = implode(', ', $values);
      if (!empty($insValues)) {
        $sqlDel = 'DELETE FROM {workbench_access_user} WHERE uid = ' . $uid;
        $sqlIns = 'INSERT INTO {workbench_access_user} (uid, access_id, access_scheme)         VALUES ' . $insValues;
        db_query($sqlDel);
        db_query($sqlIns);
      }
      $edit = array(        
        'field_article_category' => array(
          'und' => $categories,
        ),
      );
      user_save($user, $edit);
    }
```

No data is returned by `taxonomy_get_tree()`. `user_save()` is not working, but it works when called outsite `hook_cron()`.

What am I doing wrong?

taxonomy_get_tree($vid, $tid); returns empty array if i called my function from hook_cron

but if i called it from any others place it works.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code - and you're absolutely, 100% sure that `$uid` is reliably the same both in and out of the context of your cron hook? Double and triple check that by calling `_update_user_categories(1)` manually (with an appropriate hard-coded user ID), then change `$uid` to the same integer in your cron hook. That's the best way to get a reliable test, and if fails you know for sure the problem is somewhere in `_update_user_categories()`. Currently it's hard to tell because we can't see how `$uid` is being initialised

Comment: This function doesn't have this case `_update_user_categories(1)` because actually there are just two places to call this function and no one has user one.
It is running from another place from `hook_form_alter` but from `hook_cron` it fails .

Comment: You're calling the function in two different contexts - to debug, you need to hard-code the `$uid` parameter for both contexts and compare the results. We're talking really basic debugging here, you can ignore it if you want but it's not going to get your problem solved

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. print_r(taxonomy_term_load(150)) works when called normally, but is empty when called via hook_cron

Comment: May you show how you set `$uid` in `mymodule_cron()`? Without that is impossible to answer.